# Null values return when using Spatie/Laravel-Analytics Package

Tags: php, google-analytics, laravel-4.2

I am using spatie/laravel-analytics Package for my application. The value in `$response['rows']` arrives null value.

[image: Screenshot of result]

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Just fix the code that. If you want us to assist you in doing so, we need to actually see the code ^^

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank I figure out that was not the error or problem problem solved automatically. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that was not the error or problem. Analytics data arrive after some time that is due to the following reason.

> **Data processing latency**  Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to
>   Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day.
>   This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. To
>   restore intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions your
>   account sends to < 200,000 per day. For Analytics 360 accounts, this
>   limit is extended to 2 billion hits per month.

see more at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency